# node.js: Asynchronous Callback Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm pretty confused. I would love to learn how I can pass the values I get in an async function on.

I have a module with basic auth functions. In the login I ask the User model to search for a user with a given username.

```
login: function(req){
    var username = req.body.username,
        password = req.body.password;

    user.find(username);
}
```

Then the User model goes on and does that.

```
exports.find = function(username){
console.log(User.find({username: username}, function(error, users){
    // I get nice results here. But how can I pass them back.
}));
}
```

But how can I pass that user object back to the login function?

Comment: Your example code is confusing. I think what you are missing is a callback function in the `exports.find` function. But if you call this from the login function you would create infinite recursion... maybe you mixed that up in your question?

Comment: After fighting with this simple problem for so long I'm confused. One up for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback function to the method. Node.js requires a very callback-driven programming style.

For example:

```
// in your module
exports.find = function(username, callback){
    User.find({username: username}, function(error, users){
        callback(error, users);
    });
}

// elsewhere... assume you've required the module above as module
module.find(req.params.username, function(err, username) {
    console.log(username);
});
```

So you don't *return* values; you *pass in* functions that then *receive* the value (rinse, repeat)

Your login method on the User class would then look something like this:

```
login: function(req, callback){
    var username = req.body.username,
        password = req.body.password;

    user.find(username, function(err, user) {
        // do something to check the password and log the user in
        var success = true; // just as an example to demonstrate the next line
        callback(success); // the request continues
    };
}
```

Comment: Although most of this answer is on track, the comparison to "procedural" is not relevant.  The synchronous/asynchronous distinction has nothing really to do with whether the code is procedural, functional, or of some other type.

Comment: You're right; I changed it to callback-driven. In my defence it's 5am in Sydney :) Wanted to make the point you have to think differently, using callbacks instead of returning values.

Comment: Ok, we'll let this one pass.  Had it been 6AM, though... :-)

Comment: Passing a callback into user.find() was the solution. So simple, yet so essential. Thank you. Good lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass it *back* (because the function os asynchronous and `login` would already have returned when it's done). But you can pass it *ahead* to another function.